# How podscms choose template pages to use and how to choose among more of them

Tags: wordpress, templating, podscms

I'm using podscms for creating a database site.

I would like to create two different wp templates to use for detail and list Pods pages so that i can load some specific scripts and code.

But i really haven't understand in which way Pods choose the theme templates that can be used for pods pages.

I created a page called pods.php in a child theme of twenty eleven. The pods.php template is copied by the page.php with pods_content() instead of the loop.

If i leave unchanged the --Page Template-- select in the pods page setup, the pods.php template is chosen automatically.

I would like to understand how Pods choose which page template to use and how can I create two pages to choose among (eg. pods-list.php and pods-detail.php) and how to show them in the --Page Template-- select.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown of pods page templates is populated from templates in your current theme folder that contain:
/*
Template Name: Your Pods Description
*/

If you create a new template, and it does not appear in the list, click the Pods button in the Admin sidebar, and it will reload the list. Make sure you save any active pods pages, templates, or helpers before you do the reload.

Comment: Thanks, yes my templates were missing the Template Name tag!